# Difference between Application UnhandledException and AppDomain UnhandledException

Tags: c#, silverlight, unhandled-exception

I am having a silverlight application and I noticed there are two different unhandled exceptions handlers

System.Windows.Application.UnhandledException and System.AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException?

What is the difference between the two and Do I need to handle both?

My Guess is that System.Windows.Application.UnhandledException will be unhandled exception for the current thread where as AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException would be for all theads.

Comment: Application.UnhandledException is specific to exceptions that are raised by event handlers that run on the user interface thread.  Since it is the runtime that raises these events, there is no other way to trap these kind of exceptions.  And sometimes they are not fatal, you don't normally do an enormous amount of damage to program state in a Click event handler so the app might be able to limp along.  Theoretically.  Avoid handling both by *not* writing an event handler so everything bombs through AppDomain.UnhandledException.

Comment: @HansPassant, Thanks for the info, Can you please add your comments as answer and I will mark that as accepted .